# Send data using threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to know how to send data over my threads, I have this code.

```
            new Thread(BattleArena.ArenaGame(12)).Start();
```

And over BattleArena class I have

```
public static void ArenaGame(int test)
    {
        while (true)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(test);

            Thread.Sleep(400);
        }
    }
```

But that is not a valid way...

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: You should create more complete questions for others to understand better. With that little info, it's really hard to give you a correct answer on what you need.

Comment: new Thread(BattleArena.ArenaGame).Start(); Be able to send an int

Comment: I would also look at the new multi threading system in c# 5, there's lots of nice stuff in there which will help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you are "sending" the result of a method call. (Not even compilable). You want to send/execute a function:

```
new Thread(() => BattleArena.ArenaGame(12)).Start();
```

Don't use parameterized threads, they are obsolete thanks to lambdas.

To clarify: a thread is not a way to send data. It is a way to execute a function. The the function has to contain the data.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use parameterised threads. Like

```
 ThreadStart start = () => {     BattleArena.ArenaGame(12);  };

 Thread t = new Thread(start);
 t.Start();
```

Or

```
 Thread newThread = new Thread(BattleArena.ArenaGame);
 newThread.Start(12);
```

then change this method as **it only takes object as parameter as ThreadStart is not a generic delegate**

```
public static void ArenaGame(object value)
{
    int test = (int)value;
    while (true)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(test);

        Thread.Sleep(400);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use Parameterized ThreadStart